# PHP method can only be ran once [SQL]

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if you could help me find this phantom bug. The following method can only be called once when I run the script, and I get no errors regarding this. I have placed debugs everywhere, and it confirms this method is ran but the values are just NOT entered into the database the second time it is called.

Please note most of the variables and requires have been renamed with dummy names, but I know 100% that they are correct.

```
function customFunction($sql, $ID, $x, $y, $z)
{

require_once("sql.php");
require_once("econ.php");

mysqli_select_db($sql, "TheDatabase");

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO Pending (status, ID, Action, x, y, z) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$status = 'none';
$action = 'give';

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssss',  $status, $ID, $action, $x, $y, $z);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Comment: You're assuming no errors, but you have no error checking.

Comment: You're requiring the DB multiple times if you're calling the function multiple times. The better thing to do is to have the method accept `$conn`, and require `sql.php`, `econ.php` once (outside of the function).

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have error logging enabled, and I check the error log. I have been working on this project for months, this works for me

Comment: @DaveChen My bad, forget to rename the $conn var to $sql. $conn and $sql are the same thing

Comment: Requiring a file within a method is still not recommended, does it work if you pull those requirements out of the function?

Comment: Other than what @DaveChen has said there is *nothing* here which would lead us to your issue.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Well it's possible there's constraints on the columns that prevent insertion of duplicate data. Maybe the OP can `DESCRIBE Pending;`?

Comment: @DaveChen Can confirm moving the requires did not fix the issue. Trying DESCRIBE now.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yeh, that's why I came here :/

Comment: @DaveChen Bingo, thank you, had an old UNIQUE set on my timestamp column from when I was testing. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your columns in MySQL are not preventing you from inserting new data. Either read errors with `echo mysqli_error($conn);`.

Another method is to check constraints with `DESCRIBE table_name;`. In your case, `DESCRIBE Pending`.